# What can we do about the "What kind of distribution is this?" questions?

Tags: discussion

There are many questions with near identical names about 'recognizing a distribution', for example:

[What kind of distribution is figure 2 in this study?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/362595/176202)
[What kind of distribution is this via t-distribution](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/94317/176202)
[What kind of distribution is this? Many trials and guess the distributions for different settings](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/202282/176202)
[What kind of distribution is this?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/8446/176202)
[What kind of distribution is this?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/306701/176202)
[What kind of distribution is it?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/19981/176202)
[What is this distribution?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/96186/176202)
[What is this distribution?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/102628/176202)
[What distribution is this?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/172991/176202)

These seemingly identical questions clutter the related questions while they are often unrelated searches:

- About recognizing a formula;
- Recognizing a potential distribution from a plot;
- Recognizing a potential distribution from just a text description of a process;

Hence the 'related questions' may not help future visitors searching for either of these three, nor does using the search bar. Should we perhaps adopt a distinct way to name these kinds of questions, or flag them duplicate with some reference to canonical answer(s)?

Comment: +1 I believe this ambiguity and lack of good possibilities to classify/order/simplify questions/problems from a rather broad type is part of the difficulty with efficiently finding/answering questions on CV.

Comment: Perhaps a tag like [tag:distribution-identification] might be useful?

Comment: @MartijnWeterings, thanks for fixing some already. I have tagged all of these under distribution-identification and will think of a decent description of the tag.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I don't think a canonical answer is possible here.

That's just a case when more specific & descriptive titles are needed. If it's about a formula, it can be put into the title, e.g.:

> What distribution has density proportional to $(x-1) \theta^2 (1-\theta)^{x-2}$?

If it's about a plot, then I'd try to provide some description of the plot in the title:

> What is this right-skewed distribution over non-negative values?
>
> What is this weird-looking bimodal distribution (sea-level measurements)?

etc.

BTW, the last question I asked falls exactly into this category of questions:

> [How is the family of distributions with PDF proportional to $(1+ax^2)^{-1/a}$ called?](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/358940)

Comment: (+1) What about if there were a question+answer that described the properties of the most commonly encountered distributions? Wouldn't that allow us to close many of these as duplicates?

Comment: @mkt I don't know. Perhaps. But it would require a lot of work to do it well.

Comment: @mkt: I wonder whether that kind of encompassing answer would be a good fit to CV. Perhaps a list of potential resources might be helpful, like the [NIST/SEMATECH Gallery of Distributions](https://itl.nist.gov/div898/handbook/eda/section3/eda366.htm), or [Wikipedia's list of common distributions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_distribution), or a few standard textbooks.

Comment: @amoeba Agreed, it would be.

Comment: @StephanKolassa I'm not sure either. It's a kludgy workaround that lets us close a bunch of unhelpful questions, and is perhaps not worth it. I do like your tag suggestion.

Comment: Thanks @amoeba, I think changing the titles to include the category would already be a big improvement. So is it okay if I edit the example questions' titles, or should I leave that to a moderator so I don't bump all of these questions?

Comment: @FransRodenburg Mods cannot edit anything without bumping either. So I'd say you can go ahead. Thanks.